# how to get the total number parts in string split

Tags: .net, arrays

assume in a text box a user input a string like this:

```
part1,part2,part3,part4.........partn
```

how to get the total number of parts of that string

I tried using

```
dim part() as string = textbox1.text.split(",")
```

but I do not know how to get the total number of parts

Comment: The part is an array of strings. If you call the part.Count() it will return the number of elements in the array, which is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

full example

```
string textbox1_text = "part1,part2,part3,part4";
int count = textbox1_text.Split(",").Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var count = textbox1.text.Split(",").Count();
```

> **OR**

```
var count = textbox1.text.Split(",").Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

The array has a `Length` property:

```
Dim part() as string = textbox1.text.split(",")
Dim partCount as Integer = part.Length
```

If you don't need the array of parts, you can just count the commas:

```
Dim partCount as Integer = textbox1.text.Count(Function(c) c = ","c) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the problem correctly...but you could just use

```
int count = textbox1.text.Split(",").Count();
```

in C#

Comment: string a = "asd,asd,asd,asd";
int b =a.Split(',').Count(); in this case b is 4... just tested it